# what is @ in react HOC?

Tags: reactjs, content-management-system

index.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

import Main from './Main'

window.DatoCmsPlugin.init((plugin) => {
  plugin.startAutoResizer()

  const container = document.createElement('div')
  document.body.appendChild(container)

  render(<Main plugin={plugin} />, container)
})
```

Main.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import connectToDatoCms from './connectToDatoCms';
import './style.sass';

@connectToDatoCms(plugin => ({
  developmentMode: plugin.parameters.global.developmentMode,
  fieldValue: plugin.getFieldValue(plugin.fieldPath),
}))

export default class Main extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    fieldValue: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  }

  render() {
    const { fieldValue } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="container">
        {JSON.stringify(fieldValue)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

connectToDatoCms.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default mapPluginToProps => BaseComponent => (
  class ConnectToDatoCms extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = mapPluginToProps(props.plugin)
    }

    componentDidMount () {
      const { plugin } = this.props

      this.unsubscribe = plugin.addFieldChangeListener(plugin.fieldPath, () => {
        this.setState(mapPluginToProps(plugin))
      })
    }

    componentWillUnmount () {
      this.unsubscribe()
    }

    render () {
      return <BaseComponent {...this.props} {...this.state} />
    }
  }
)
```

I used this command to generate a starter code for datoCMS plugin, `npx -p yo -p generator-datocms-plugin -c 'yo datocms-plugin'`.

What is `@` in `@connectToDatoCms`, Main.jsx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@connectToDatoCms` uses the decorator pattern.

Your webpack config in your code is setup to process decorators, probably using [`babel-plugin-transform-decorators`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-decorators/)

Decorators are similar to HOCs

`Decorators` are just a wrapper around a function. They are used to enhance the functionality of the function without modifying the underlying function.

With the current HOC syntax pattern the above could have been used as

```
import connectToDatoCms from './connectToDatoCms';
import './style.sass';

class Main extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    fieldValue: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  }

  render() {
    const { fieldValue } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="container">
        {JSON.stringify(fieldValue)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapPluginToProps = plugin => ({
    developmentMode: plugin.parameters.global.developmentMode,
    fieldValue: plugin.getFieldValue(plugin.fieldPath),
 })
export default connectToDatoCms(mapPluginToProps)(Main);
```

Comment: thanks, so what does it actually do in the above snippet?

Comment: It actually adds another functionality to Main component, I added its equivalent in terms of regular HOC in the post too. The function argument passed to `@connectToDatoCms` is invoked whenever `mapPluginToProps` is called from within the HOC.. Its an alternate syntax to HOC